# Do I need an I-94 form at any of the US airports?

Tags: i-94

I am a Mexican national with a tourist visa. I will be crossing overland to El Paso TX, to take a connecting flight from El Paso to Atlanta then out to Seoul, Korea, to end up in Cambodia. Do I need an I-94 form at any of the US airports?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, if you have a paper I-94, you should give it to the airline when you check in for your flight to Korea.  If they do not give you a paper I-94, and perhaps even if they do, your departure will be recorded when the airline passes your passport information to CBP.

But you won't "need" the form anywhere, and if you have one but forget to hand it to the airline, nothing much will happen.  In this case, if your departure is for some reason not recorded, you can mail your I-94 and boarding passes to an address in Ohio to have your records updated.

You can check your I-94 database records at the [CBP's I-94 site](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov), and you can get more information about updating your records on their page [I still have my I-94](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/kw/i94).

We also have several related questions on this site:

- [Where to return I-94 form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44389/19400)
- [Will I get any trouble after forgetting to return I-94 form on time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61027/19400)
- [Do I need to return my I-94 to CBSA if I know this isn't my last visit within the I-94 validity?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109235/19400)
- [Does returning my I-94 at the Canadian border make any difference at all?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109383/19400)
- [I forgot to give back the I94-W form and departed from a Mexican airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111066/19400)
- [How can I ensure my exit from the US by land is recorded?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93520/19400)